Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg Method to Solve 3rd Order ODE in Fortran 95
I need help to build Fortran 95 code that solves 3rd order ODE using Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg method. I am trying to solve y''' = -2y''+y'+2y with y(0)=3, y'(0)=-2, and y''(0)=6. The exact solution should be
y=exp(-2t)+exp(-t)+exp(t)
The plot shows comparison of it with the computation.
My plot
And here is my code.
program ft

    !testing 45 rk method by examining y''' = -2y''+y'+2y, y''(0)=6, y'(0)=-2, and y(0)=3.
    !the exact solution should be y = exp(-2t)+exp(-t)+exp(t)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: i = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (10,200)
    REAL(i) :: t, val(3), dt, newval(3), newdt
    logical :: redo
    external runge

    t = 0.0

    !val = (y,y',y'')
    !initial condition
    val = (/3.0,-2.0,6.0/)
    !step size
    dt = 1.0E-4

    open (10, file = 'RK_test.dat', status = 'new')
    do while (t<4.0)
        redo = .true.
        write(10,*) t, val(1), val(2), val(3)

        do while (redo)
            call runge(t, dt, val, newdt, redo, newval)
            dt = newdt
        end do
        val = newval
        t = t + dt
    end do
    close(10)

end program ft

subroutine runge(t, dt, val, newdt, recalc, valp1)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: i = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (10,200)
    REAL(i), parameter :: deltacalc(2,6) = reshape([16.0/135, 0.0, 6656.0/12825, 28561.0/56430, -9.0/50, 2.0/55, &
                25.0/216, 0.0, 1408.0/2565,   2197.0/4104,  -1.0/5,  0.0], shape(deltacalc), order=[2,1])
    REAL(i), parameter :: coe(6,6) = reshape ([0.0,         0.0,          0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                           1.0/4,       0.0,          0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                           3.0/32,      9.0/32,       0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                           1932.0/2197, -7200.0/2197, 7296.0/2197,  0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                           439.0/216,   -8.0,         3680.0/513,   -845.0/4104, 0.0,      0.0, &
                                           -8.0/27,     2.0,          -3544.0/2565, 1859.0/4104, -11.0/40, 0.0], &
                                           shape(coe), order=[2,1])
    REAL(i) :: valbar(3), k(6,3), delta(3), error(3), var(3), f(3)
    REAL(i), intent(in) :: t, dt, val(3)
    REAL(i), intent(out) :: newdt, valp1(3)
    logical, intent(out) :: recalc
    integer :: a, b, c, d
    External func

    k = 0
    valbar = val
    valp1 = val
    var = val

    do a = 1,6
        do b = 1,3
            do c = 1,6
                do d = 1,3
                    var(d) = var(d) + coe(a,c)*k(c,d)
                end do
            end do
            call func(var, f)
            k(a,b) = dt*f(b)
        end do
    end do
    recalc = .false.

    do b = 1, 3
        if (val(b)==0.0) then
            error(b) = 1.0E-3
        else
            error(b) = 10.0**(log10(abs(val(b)))-3.0)
        end if


        do a = 1, 6
            valbar(b) = valbar(b) + k(a,b)*deltacalc(1,a)
            valp1(b) = valp1(b) + k(a,b)*deltacalc(2,a)
        end do

        delta(b) = 0.84*(error(b)/(abs(valbar(b) - valp1(b))/dt))**(1.0/4) 
        
        if (abs(valbar(b) - valp1(b))/dt>error(b)) then
            recalc = .true.
            !print*, "oooops"
        end if
    end do


    newdt = minval(delta)*dt
    if (newdt > 0.01) then
        newdt = 0.01
    end if

end subroutine runge

subroutine func(var, out)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: i = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (10,200)
    REAL(i), intent(in) :: var(3)
    REAL(i), intent(out) :: out(3)

    out(1) = var(2) 
    out(2) = var(3)
    out(3) = -2*var(3) + var(2) + 2*var(1)
end subroutine func

This is linear ODE. Thus I expect that the computation match the solution much better. Please let me know if I am wrong about this.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Welcome, please show us the actual numbers you are getting, not just a plot. Are they changing or just constant?  Be aware that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and problems with implementation of numerical algorithms might be better on topic at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/  It is not realistic at Stack Overflow to ask to identify why a whole program gives incorrect results, that is generally too much to ask and too broad.

It is strange to name the procedure "runge". Carl Runge re-opened the topic in 1895 with a 3rd order 4 stage method, Kutta gave the general schemes for RK methods in 1901, but only valid examples up to 4th order. The method was developed by Fehlberg, among other pairs demonstrating the difference between enhancing known methods by an embedded step and explicitly constructing embedded methods employing the fsal principle.

Please encapsulate the vector operations in function calls. The first obvious error should resolve itself, perhaps you can even find out what it was.

@Takashi Katayama: if you don't change the timestep in response to your error estimates then your code works fine. Maybe try to talk us through your error estimation and what is going on with the timestep changes.

@Takashi Katayama: For discussing possible issues in your program, it may also be useful to post it to https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/ (particularly when the test program is long)

Note that 99.9% of modern computers use IEEE 748 floats, use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env with the real64 constant already defined to be the same as the SELECTED_REAL_KIND() statement above.

Note #2, move the end program statement to the end of the file, and use the contains keyword before your helper function definitions. This way all the parameters and variables defined in the program are also visible to the functions and you do not need to keep defining integer, parameter :: i over and over  again.

Try putting a !DIR$ REAL:8 in the start of the code to force all real variables to be of 64-bit type. You have a mix of types here, like 1e-4 is a 32-bit real, and the equivalent 64-bit would be 1d-4

This is not going to solve the problem, but you can write do c = 1,a-1 for the c loop as  this is an explicit ODE method and all the coefficients at the diagonal and above are zero.

One thing to be careful of here (which is a common Fortran mistake): these numbers you have 2197.0/4104, 10.0, are single precision numbers, so you are not getting the full accuracy you think you are. To make them double precision, you have to define them like this: 2197.0_i/4104.0_i, 10.0_i, etc. (where you used i to define the real kind...I would recommend something more meaningful such as rk or wp).

Most compilers have a extend precision of constants option, right?

I think you need to reset var at each stage back to val
k = 0
valbar = val
valp1 = val
! move "var = val" inside the loop

do a = 1,6
    do b = 1,3
        var = val
        
        do c = 1,6
            do d = 1,3
                var(d) = var(d) + coe(a,c)*k(c,d)
            end do
        end do            
                    
        call func(var, f)
        k(a,b) = dt*f(b)
        
    end do
end do


Here is the full code with some minor fixes, including replacing SELECT_REAL_KIND() with ISO_FORTRAN_ENV constant, and forcing all variables to be double precision using a compiler directive.
Also a minor restructuring of the subs to be after a contains statement in the program in order to share parameters and remove the need to declare external functions.
Finally, the screen displays every 20th solution step, in addition to the file output.
!DIR$ REAL:8    
program FortranOdeConsole1
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: i => real64
implicit none

! integer, parameter :: i = SELECTED_REAL_KIND (10,200)
REAL(i) :: t, val(3), dt, newval(3), newdt
logical :: redo
integer :: index
real(i), parameter :: maxdt = 0.01

t = 0.0
!val = (y,y',y'')
!initial condition
val = [ 3.0, -2.0, 6.0 ]
!step size
dt = 1.0d-4
index = 0
open (10, file = 'RK_test.dat', status = 'REPLACE')
write(10,*) t, val(1), val(2), val(3)

write(*,'(*(1x,a14))') "time", "val(1)", "val(2)", "val(3)"
write(*,'(*(1x,g14.6))') t, val(1), val(2), val(3)    

do while (t<4.0)
    redo = .true.

    do while (redo)
        call runge(t, dt, val, newdt, redo, newval)
        dt = newdt
    end do
    val = newval
    t = t + dt
    index = index + 1
    
    write(10,*) t, val(1), val(2), val(3)
    
    if( mod(index, 20) == 0) then
        write(*,'(*(1x,g14.6))') t, val(1), val(2), val(3)    
    end if
end do
! final step
close(10)
    
contains

subroutine runge(t, dt, val, newdt, recalc, valp1)
REAL(i), parameter :: deltacalc(2,6) = reshape([16.0/135, 0.0, 6656.0/12825, 28561.0/56430, -9.0/50, 2.0/55, &
            25.0/216, 0.0, 1408.0/2565,   2197.0/4104,  -1.0/5,  0.0], shape(deltacalc), order=[2,1])
REAL(i), parameter :: coe(6,6) = reshape ([0.0,         0.0,          0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                       1.0/4,       0.0,          0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                       3.0/32,      9.0/32,       0.0,          0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                       1932.0/2197, -7200.0/2197, 7296.0/2197,  0.0,         0.0,      0.0, &
                                       439.0/216,   -8.0,         3680.0/513,   -845.0/4104, 0.0,      0.0, &
                                       -8.0/27,     2.0,          -3544.0/2565, 1859.0/4104, -11.0/40, 0.0], &
                                       shape(coe), order=[2,1])
REAL(i) :: valbar(3), k(6,3), delta(3), error(3), var(3), f(3)
REAL(i), intent(in) :: t, dt, val(3)
REAL(i), intent(out) :: newdt, valp1(3)
logical, intent(out) :: recalc
integer :: a, b, c, d

k = 0
valbar = val
valp1 = val
!var = val

do a = 1,6
    do b = 1,3
        var = val
        
        do c = 1,6
            do d = 1,3
                var(d) = var(d) + coe(a,c)*k(c,d)
            end do
        end do            
                    
        call func(var, f)
        k(a,b) = dt*f(b)
        
    end do
end do
recalc = .false.

do b = 1, 3
    if (val(b)==0.0) then
        error(b) = 1.0E-3
    else
        error(b) = 10.0**(log10(abs(val(b)))-3.0)
    end if

    do a = 1, 6
        valbar(b) = valbar(b) + k(a,b)*deltacalc(1,a)
        valp1(b) = valp1(b) + k(a,b)*deltacalc(2,a)
    end do

    delta(b) = 0.84*(error(b)/(abs(valbar(b) - valp1(b))/dt))**(1.0/4) 
    
    if (abs(valbar(b) - valp1(b))/dt>error(b)) then
        recalc = .true.
        !print*, "oooops"
    end if
end do

newdt = min(minval(delta)*dt, maxdt)

end subroutine runge    

pure subroutine func(Y, Yp)
!implicit none
real(i), intent(in) :: Y(3)
real(i), intent(out) :: Yp(3)
    Yp(1) = Y(2)
    Yp(2) = Y(3)
    Yp(3) = -2*Y(3) + Y(2) + 2*Y(1)
end subroutine 

end program

The screen output is
           time         val(1)         val(2)         val(3)
    0.00000        3.00000       -2.00000        6.00000
   0.200000        2.71997      -0.984955        4.77115
   0.400000        2.61243      -0.116489        3.98738
   0.600000        2.66566       0.635462        3.58731
   0.800000        2.86335        1.33795        3.48115
    1.00000        3.20108        2.04388        3.61521
    1.20000        3.68413        2.79815        3.96173
    1.40000        4.32633        3.64215        4.51241
    1.60000        5.14972        4.61718        5.27445
    1.80000        6.18487        5.76737        6.26848
    2.00000        7.47163        7.14222        7.52767
    2.20000        9.06054        8.79916        9.09810
    2.40000        11.0146        10.8062        11.0398
    2.60000        13.4117        13.2448        13.4286
    2.80000        16.3478        16.2137        16.3592
    3.00000        19.9405        19.8323        19.9481
    3.20000        24.3337        24.2463        24.3388
    3.40000        29.7038        29.6329        29.7072
    3.60000        36.2661        36.2086        36.2683
    3.80000        44.2839        44.2372        44.2855
    4.00000        54.0791        54.0411        54.0802

